# Search Volume Impact on Avg ranking

Tags: seo, search

Looking at last year's data, I see that searches were way higher, especially for retail ecommerce websites. This year as things are going back to normal, search volume is also down. I want confirmation if my hypothesis is correct here. Last year Google was prioritizing sites that had plenty of stock and authority sites like Walmart, Amazon etc. This year, things are normal, so sites ranking high in search don't need to be in top positions; hence, the rankings are down.

If the search volume is down, does that impact the CTR/clicks etc.?

Comment: Can you say how this affects your own website?   Questions here are on-topic if they focus on running a website but not just when focused on general ranking trends.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think that maybe they are talking about _their_ data from the past year?